# Generate SOAP service in mule using WSDL file

Tags: mule, mule-studio

i am trying to create a soap service in mule using a wsdl file. but i am getting following error -

Error generating from WSDL
Could not find velocity template file
org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/frontend/jaxws/template/client.vm

Another thing:
In mule is there any tool to create WSDL file.
Is it necessary in mule that for every WSDL file it will create java classes. 
I am facing little difficulties while doing top down(wsdl first) development. Please suggest me if there is any tutorial.

Comment: Add your wsdl file here. Also mentioned the process you tried to generate SOAP service from WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule's SOAP web service stack is based on CXF so use the code generator from CXF to generate client classes from each of your WSDLs.

This is described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Also note that it's possible to call remote web services without generating client classes but it's very limited (only simple types can be used, no complex ones), see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/WSDL+Connectors